# In MYSQL, how to see if a time value falls between two other time values when they span a day

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

| id | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15:00 | 23:00 |
| 2 | 15:30 | 01:00 |

I need a SQL statement that returns all the rows that fall between a particular time.

`select * from table where start_time <= '22:00' and end_time > '22:00'`

If that time is 22:00 for example, then both rows above should be returned, however because 01:00 is not less than 22:00 then the 2nd row is not returned. *In fact row 2 will never be returned because nothing is greater than something that it is less than, if you see what I mean!*

There is no date field in the table and it is assumed that the row cannot last more than 24 hours.

Is there a way to do this without using a stored procedure?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If start time is less than end time, you want to check if the given time is between them, because they're on the same day.

If start time is after end time, it means the time range crosses over midnight, so you want to check if the given time is *not* between them.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE IF(start_time < end_time, 
         '22:00' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time,
         '22:00' NOT BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that works! I was trying to achieve the same thing using brackets but it wasn't working, and I didn't know about using the 'if' statement in the middle of a SQL query.

Comment: However, this is the same problem that I posted earlier that you marked down and incorrectly closed off, wrongly saying that it had been answered already. Please read the question more clearly next time - it cost me an hour and a half.

Comment: I didn't close that one, I just posted a comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I wonder who it was - happened only a few minutes after I posted it..